# Elasticsearch dsl python, natural key for document?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document which looks like

```
{

   date_at: '2020-10-01',
   foo_id: 3,
   value: 5
}
```

When `date_at` and `foo_id` are defined, document is uniquely defined.

So I'd like to do something like

```
MyDocument.update_or_create(date_at=date_at, foo_id=foo_id, {value: some_value})
```

If a document with given `date_at and foo_id` exists, update the document, otherwise create the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update or create a document (what ES calls "upsert"), you need to go through the [update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) and that API requires a document ID.

Selecting a document with a specific `date_at` and `foo_id` would be the job of the [update by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) but that API doesn't support "upserting" (i.e. create or update).

So, if your documents are uniquely defined by `date_at` and `foo_id`, I'd suggest giving them IDs that contain those two values, like for instance `2020-10-01:3`. Doing so would allow you to leverage the update API like this:

```
POST your-index/_update/2020-10-01:3
{
  "doc": {
    "value": "some_value",
    "date_at": "2020-10-01",
    "foo_id": 3
  },
  "doc_as_upsert": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be creating daily indices and using `foo_id` as document id. Then upserting would be as simple as:

```json
PUT your-index-2020-10-01/_doc/3
{
  "value": "some_value",
  "date_at": "2020-10-01",
  "foo_id": 3
}
```

`foo_id` would be always unique within the index.

Comment: that's a valid approach as well. I guess range querying would be easier with single index. on the other hand, this approach will distribute larger data better.

Comment: _I guess range querying would be easier with single index_. Not necessarily, you can easily assign an alias to all of your indices with a date field, or alternatively query index with a wildcard: `GET your-index-*/_search`.